# how to print lines with specific column matching members of array in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
#!/bin/bash    
awk '$1 == "abc" {print}' file # print lines first column matching "abc"
```

How to print lines when the first column matching members of array("12" or "34" or "56")?

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=("12" "34" "56")
```

**Add**
Also, how to print lines when the first column exactly matching members of array("12" or "34" or "56")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `bash` to interpolate the string to a regex pattern used in `Awk`, by changing the `IFS` value to a `|` character and do array expansion as below:

```
ARR=("12" "34" "56")    

regex=$( IFS='|'; echo "${ARR[*]}" )
awk -v str="$regex" '$1 ~ str' file
```

The array expansion converts the list elements to a string delimited with `|`, for e.g. `12|34|56` in this case.

The `$()` runs in the sub-shell do that the value of `IFS` is not reflcted in the parent shell. You could make it in one line as

```
awk -v str="$( IFS='|'; echo "${ARR[*]}" )" '$1 ~ str' file
```

---

OP had also asked for an *exact* match of the strings from the array in the file, in that case using `grep` with its ERE support can do the job

```
regex=$( IFS='|'; echo "${ARR[*]}" )
egrep -w "$regex" file
```

(or)

```
grep -Ew "$regex" file
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** one-liner

```
awk -v var="${ARR[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(var,array," "); for(i in array) a[array[i]] } ($1 in a){print $0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the trick:

```
awk 'BEGIN{myarray [0]="aaa";myarray [1]="bbb"; test=0 }{

test=0;
for ( x in myarray ) {
    if($1 == myarray[x]){
    test=1;
    break;
    }

}
if(test==0) print}'
```

If you need to pass a variable to awk use the -v option, however for array it is a bit tricker but the following syntax should work.

```
A=( $( ls -1p ) ) #example of list to be passed to awk (to be adapted to your needs)

awk -v var="$A" 'BEGIN{split(var,list,"\n")}END{ for (i in list) print i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Near the same as Inian

```
ARR=("34" "56" "12");regex=" ${ARR[*]} ";regex="'^${regex// /\\|^}'";grep -w $regex infile
```